# CSS transition not working with underline

Tags: html, css

I am using css to make an underline  come under a span:

**CSS:**

```
.un{
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.un:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="un"> Underlined Text - Or to be underlined </span>
```

The underline simply appears, it doesn't move in over .5 seconds, like the `transition` should apply. Why not? How can I make this work?

Comment: Hi yak613, have you tried this on multiple browsers? Some browsers such as old versions of IE do not allow for transitions.

Comment: Getting the code right is probably a better idea than blaming older versions. The transition of the text-decoration property is the problem at hand here, even for modern browsers. [Transition support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) is pretty established by now.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

### Updated for 2021:

The support for `text-decoration-color` has come a long way, and common browser support requirements have loosened making it a viable option for most new projects. If you are only seeking a color transition, and can do without IE support, see [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53139326/3285730).

---

### Original answer:

You cannot change the color of the `text-decoration` independent of the `color`. However, you can achieve a similar effect with pseudo elements:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text - Or to be underlined</span>
```

That is the most customizable way to do it, you can get all sorts of transitions. (Try playing around with the margins/alignment. You can make some awesome effects without adding to your HTML)
But if you just want a simple underline, use a border:

```css
.un {
  transition: 300ms;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.un:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<span class="un"> Underlined Text - Or to be underlined </span>
```

Comment: can't wait till css4 comes out then. maybe transitions will work like that then.

Comment: Border bottom doesn't work like underline with multiline text.

Comment: @karoluS it does if you set the display to inline rather than inline-block

Comment: The problem with pseudo-element is that it doesn't work with multiline text

Comment: ( Did the (original) question say anything about the text-decoration-COLOR ? Cause at time of writing this comment the answer seems kind of off-topic but is still marked as correct answer. )

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker this question/answer were both posted significantly before `text-decoration-color` was supported well enough to be used on production environments.

Answer (score 49):

A proper solution that will work with multiple line text and doesn't require border-bottom mockup should look like this. It utilizes `text-decoration-color` property.

Have in mind that it's not [supported by old browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color)

```css
.underlined-text{
 text-decoration: underline;
 text-decoration-color: transparent;
 transition: 1s;

 /*add those for opera and mozilla support*/
 -webkit-text-decoration-color: transparent;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: transparent;
}

.underlined-text:hover{
 text-decoration-color: red;
 
 /*add those for opera and mozilla support*/
 -webkit-text-decoration-color: red;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="underlined-text">You're the greatest thing that has ever been or ever will be. You're special. You're so very special. It is a lot of fun. You don't want to kill all your dark areas they are very important. In your world you can create anything you desire.</span>
```

Comment: This is a better approach than the accepted answer, and I don't see a problem with its browser support.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue with `a` tags and I figured it out.

The reason it's not animating is because you cannot transition from a `text-decoration: none` value.

In my case, what I did was set `text-decoration-color` to `transparent` and then, on `:hover`, set the `text-decoration-color` to the color value I wanted.

In your particular case, you would have to specifiy `text-decoration: underline transparent` since `span` tags have an initial `text-decoration` value of `none`. Then, on `:hover`, specify the `text-decoration-color` that you want.

FWIW, `text-decoration` and `text-decoration-color` are animatable properties, according to MDN.

References:

- [Animatable CSS Properties - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2020. Works in everything except Microsoft based browsers.

Comment: Best 'bug' soliving reason. Thank!

Answer (score 7):

The answer of @Jacob is pretty neat. But I accidentally found a solution no one have provided:

```css
.un {
  transition: .4s;
}

.un:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #7f7f7f;
}
```

```html
<span class="un"> Underlined Text - Or to be underlined </span>
```

Use `box-shadow` with no blur can achieve underline effects even more tricky and special.
***This can make your page run slower if you use a lot of it.***

Comment: This is great answer and worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `border-bottom` instead, like so:

```css
.un{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;    
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.un:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;    
}
```

```html
<span class="un"> Underlined Text - Or to be underlined </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround to add fade animation to the underline property:

```
.un{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #0000;
    transition: .2s;
}
.un:hover{
    text-decoration-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `text-decoration` is an all-or-nothing property, you’ll probably want to try using a `border-bottom` instead. This is how I’ve done it previously:

```css
.un {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in;
}
.un:hover {
    border-color: black; /* use whatever color matches your text */
}
```

```html
Text that is <span class="un">wrapped in the “un” class</span> has a border-bottom that appears as an underline that fades in.
```

Applying the transition to the border color change from transparent to your text color should give the appearance of a “fade in” from *no underline* to *underline*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an underline with increasing width like below, you can use `background-image` instead.

```css
.un {
  display: inline;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e876f5, #e876f5);
  /*                   ↓ height of underline  */
  background-size: 0% 2px;
  /*                        ↓ y position of underline. you can change as 50% to see it. */
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background 0.3s linear;
}

.un:hover {
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">hover me</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to work best, clean and simple. The transition works once you specify a color.

@ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-line.asp

```
a {
    color: #222;
    -webkit-text-decoration: none transparent;
            text-decoration: none transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
    color: #222;
    -webkit-text-decoration: underline #222;
            text-decoration: underline #222;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by animating the `text-decoration-color` property.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

```css
.un {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
  transition: text-decoration-color 1s;
}

.un:hover {
  text-decoration-color: currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text - Or to be underlined</span>
```

(This is possible now that IE has reached EOL.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I moved the border up closer.

```
<style type="text/css">
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(126,93,142);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    color: #ce40ce;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}</style>

<a href="#">La La La</a>
```